# Historical question needs closing/deleting

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, vote-to-delete

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018018/online-vss-for-asp-net) a question that can be abridged as follows:

"Source control, recommend me a free one plz"

I'm currently the accepted answer. My answer was link-only to a document that is now over ten years old. I was surprised to be awarded an upvote on it recently. Changing my answer to a comprehensive review of the current state of SCM seems out of scope to me. As my close vote last week has not gained any traction and my bad answer is neither deleteable nor salvageable, I've come here to ask for help killing it.

Comment: Very few views (and no offensive to your post - barely any information at all) - definitely off-topic. I've closed and deleted.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy My answer was terrible, hence the post here. Thanks for slaying it.

Comment: Amazingly, the link in your post had not gone dead, despite being to a Microsoft blog, which seem to go down every 2-3 weeks like clockwork.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, Microsoft. Something about needing to reboot older versions of Windows once a month because of the way they handled time.

Comment: "*You the real MVP*", @spender

Comment: Now you have a "featured meta post" on deleting an deleted question, lol. Wanna ask on meta-meta to delete this question?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse well he can't doit himself because of upvotes so ... :D

Comment: @Walfrat as long as there isn't an upvoted answer, the asker can delete its own question with a single step.